# Flutter - syncing sqlite database on iCloud?

Tags: flutter, sqlite, icloud

With Flutter, is there a good way to create a sqlite database that persists data across devices (i.e. by syncing the database to iCloud)?

I don't want to use Firestore or anything else that could create recurring server costs for me as the app developer, but I would like it to be possible for users to persist their data across devices.

I'm primarily looking to do this for an iOS/MacOS app, but if there's a way to do it that would also work for Android devices, bonus points for that.

I am currently using the sqflite package for a SQLite database.